# Wpf DataTemplate referencing itself; DataContext (= null) issues

Tags: wpf, recursion, casting, datatemplate

I have a view. Inside of this view I use my custom control GrMenu.

```
<pages:PageBase>
   <Grid>
     <views:GrMenu x:Name="InsightsMenu" Menu="{Binding Insights}" SelectItemCommand="{Binding LoadInsightCommand}" SelectedMenuItem="{Binding SelectedInsight, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
   </Grid>
</pages:PageBase>
```

GrMenu is basically something like a tree view but realised using ItemsControls.

```
<UserControl x:Name="GrMenuUserControl" x:Class="Views.GrMenu">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <telerik:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
        <telerik:InvertedBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="InvertedBooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
        <converters:BoolToColourConverter x:Key="BoolToColourConverter" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type groupingMenu:IMenuItem}">
            <Grid>
                <telerik:RadExpander HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="{Binding HasChildren, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <telerik:RadExpander.Header>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Header}" />
                    </telerik:RadExpander.Header>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <InlineUIContainer>
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MenuItemTemplate}" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                        </InlineUIContainer>
                    </TextBlock>
                </telerik:RadExpander>
                <Button 
                    Visibility="{Binding HasChildren, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
                    Content="{Binding Header}"
                    MinWidth="200"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="20,2,2,2" 
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Click="MenuItemButton_OnClick"
                    Tag="{Binding Id}"
                    Command="{Binding SelectItemCommand, ElementName=GrMenuUserControl}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                    Background="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColourConverter}}"
                    />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=GrMenuUserControl}">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="GroupedMenuItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Menu.GroupedMenuItems}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MenuItemTemplate}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And my page base (the class where the exception is firing) looks like that:

```
public abstract class PageBase : Page
{
    protected PageBase()
    {
        Unloaded += Page_Unloaded;
    }

    public void Page_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(DataContext!=null)
            DataContext = null;            
    }
}
```

And here's the thing. When I'm navigating to my screen and then away I'm invoking the Page_Unloaded method which tries to assign null to the DataContext but fails saying:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate' to type 'System.Windows.DataTemplate'.
```

I've figured out that the problem relates to this line:

```
                    <InlineUIContainer>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MenuItemTemplate}" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                    </InlineUIContainer>
```

as if I only take out the ItemTemplate attribute everything works fine but then I lose the data template recursion privilege.

Do you guys know of any workaround I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found where the issue was. So silly!

The only thing I've changed to make it work is the x:Key attribute value of my data template. I guess it was a forbidden name or something..

The new solution:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemDataTemplate">

<InlineUIContainer>
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MenuItemDataTemplate}" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
</InlineUIContainer>

<ItemsControl x:Name="GroupedMenuItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Menu.GroupedMenuItems}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MenuItemDataTemplate}"/>
```